# How to detector or extract number from the speech using vosk library

Tags: android, speech-recognition, vosk

**How to detector or  extract number from the speech using vosk library**

> i have implemented vosk library to recognise speech in Android, now i am able to recognise speech .

> **But** , I want to detect digits as numeric currently library returning word of numeric speech.**Like** if speech is   1 2 3 4 And 1005 so Result will be : one two three four  And one thousand one

> **Out put should be :** 1 2 3 4   And 1005

**Android demo Project for libarary:** [Demo Linlk](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-android-demo)

Comment: I think you can replace the words "one", "two", "three" with numbers in your application. onPartialResult(String hypothesis) { hypothesis =  hypothesis.replace("one","1"); ... Or you will have to adapt the model https://alphacephei.com/vosk/adaptation